# Voice recognition in Windows

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows, xaml

I need to perform actions in my Desktop app when a user says certain things, for example, "Save Document" or "Save As" or "Save changes" will raise its corresponding event.

But I don't want to rely on, or even implement buttons (this is an app for me). So setting the AccessibleName or whatever is not good enough. I need more control.

Is there a way to "listen" for commands in a Windows WPF Desktop app? Then raise an event when that command has been spoken?

Comment: Thanks for your answers everyone, I am currently checking out the links you gave me now.

Answer (score 2):

Since everyone is posting links to Microsoft Speech API, you might still be lost at how to use it.

So here is a [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-in-Csharp) for using [Microsoft Speech API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125663%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I have linked to a code example of MSDN, it wasn't just that obvious ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen the [Microsoft Speech API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125663%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which supports [speech recognition](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125077%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#API_Speech_Recognition)?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the [Microsoft Speech API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361683%28v=office.14%29.aspx) (This is a *Get Started with Speech Recognition* with a neat code example. Though it is for WinForms it should work for WPF too.). It allows you to create a grammar which can be recognized and input handled.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking into adding speech recognition to my fork of Hotspotizer Kinect-based app (http://github.com/birbilis/hotspotizer)

> After some search I see you can't markup the actionable UI elements
>   with related speech commands in order to simulate user actions on them
>   as one would expect if Speech input was integrated in WPF. I'm
>   thinking of making a XAML markup extension to do that, unless someone
>   can point to pre-existing work on this that I could reuse...

the following links should be useful:

http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/audio-video/speech-recognition-making-wpf-listen/

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/programming-speech-in-wpf-speech-recognition/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rlucero/archive/2012/01/17/speech-recognition-exploring-grammar-based-recognition.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855387.aspx (make use of Kinect mic array audio input)

http://kin-educate.blogspot.gr/2012/06/speech-recognition-for-kinect-easy-way.html

https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/KinectQuickstart/Audio-Fundamentals

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh855359.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Software_Requirements

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27225

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27226

http://www.redmondpie.com/speech-recognition-in-a-c-wpf-application/

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/55383/A-WPF-Voice-Commanded-Database-Management-Applicat

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/483347/Speech-recognition-speech-to-text-text-to-speech-a

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/nipuntomar/speech-to-text-in-wpf/

http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh361625(v=office.14).aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh323806.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.requestrecognizerupdate.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rlucero/archive/2012/02/03/speech-recognition-using-multiple-grammars-to-improve-recognition.aspx